# Bootstrap navbar grid system for unordered list

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, grid, navbar

Can anyone help me please how to make the unordered list display in grid widths ?

```
<div class="navbar" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="navbar-header col-md-4">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topmenu">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a rel="home" class="logo" href="{$baseUri}">
            <img src="img/layout/portfolio-2014-logo.png" alt="" class="img-responsive logo" />
        </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="topmenu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#section-gallery">blog</a></li>
            <li class="col-md-2"><a href="#section-news">works</a></li>
            <li class="col-md-2"><a href="#section-bio">about</a></li>
            <li class="col-md-2"><a href="#section-contact">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>  
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    <hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried something like this but it is not workiing :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that's not part of default Bootstrap in the navbar because navbar-nav does it's own width based on the width of the text and the padding, but you can just remove the navbar-nav and just use nav:

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/kiyiye/1/

```
    <ul class="nav">
```

And it will work with col-*-classes but you'll need to likely address the smaller viewport margins and such. Get intimately familiar with Bootstrap's css if you decide to use something never demonstrated in their docs.